# SQL Database Design Relationship Choices

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'd like some advice about how to go about creating a database for the following situation:

- I want to track my work hours.
- I'll have three entities: Shifts, Category, Location (Example: 6am to 6pm, Nursing, Brisbane Hospital).

I understand the shifts can have one category and one location. So the main question is: Should Category and Location contain a list of shifts? Or I should let the front ent of my app deal with displaying things like "Shifts Per Category" or "Shifts per Location"?

Thank you!

Comment: The latter. Do you want a `Person` table also? Are Categories limited in which Location or Shift they could possibly apply to, or is anything possible anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I would personally design it such that there was one more table called `ShiftCategoryLocations` (or named something a little more user friendly) that had every logical combination of `ShiftId`, `CategoryId`, and `LocationId`. It would also have its own primary key `ShiftCategoryLocationId` (or whatever name made more sense) so that your `WorkHourLog` table could reference the 3 dimensions easily by only having a **foreign key** relationship on `ShiftCategoryLocationId`. This is known as a dimensions combinations table.

While for *small* data you could definitely recreate the relations as needed in the application side, but the most efficiency will be if it existed in the database. It also is more reusable and readable in a sense by being refactored into one place, the database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that shifts would have one category and one location.
Each location would have a fixed number of categories.
Each category would have a fixed number of shift-available.
shift-worked would identify the location + category + shift-available
Thus it would be relatively simple to have one table (available-shifts)  with  the columns
location  | category | shift-available | shift-id (unique)
then a second table (worked) with  columns
date | shift-id with worked.shift-id = available-shifts.shift-id.
This way you only have to make entries in the (worked) table with date and the matching shift-id from the available-shifts table to have all the needed data to match location, category, date, and time.